# "NOT" clause in active android?

Tags: sqlite, select, activeandroid

Anybody know how to do "NOT" clause in Active Android Select Query?

My code is :

```
ArrayList<MyModel> arrayList = new Select().from(MyModel.class).where("userId NOT","1").execute();
```

This one does not work.How do I implement not clause here?Here userId is my column name.I want to get the List of values except for the userId of 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the SQL syntax

```
ArrayList<MyModel> arrayList = new Select().from(MyModel.class).where("userId <> 1").execute();
```

Or if you want to take the value 1 from a variable like x

```
ArrayList<MyModel> arrayList = new Select().from(MyModel.class).where("userId <> ?", x).execute();
```

Comment: @AjayJayendran `<>` is the "not equal" operator in sql, the sql equivalent of `!=` in Java.